Magento2 di:compile Error: Interface Magento\InventoryApi\Model\SourceValidatorInterface
After upgrading from magento 2.3.7 to 2.4.6 I am getting this error while running di:compile
There is an error in /vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup/Model/Source/Validator/PhoneValidator.php at line: 19 
Interface "Magento\InventoryApi\Model\SourceValidatorInterface" not found#0 /public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()

